# Why this term can be written as the electric force component of the lorentz law?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, forces

I am reading Special Relativity and Classical Field Theory by Susskind. In chapter 6, he is deriving the Lorentz force law from the action, and he presents the following equation $$m\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\dot{X_p}}{\sqrt{1-\dot{x}^2}} = e\left(\frac{\partial A_0}{\partial X^p} - \frac{\partial A_p}{\partial t}\right) + e\dot{X^n}\left(\frac{\partial A_n}{\partial X^p} - \frac{\partial A_p}{\partial X^n}\right)$$Then he says we can see easily that the first term on the right is the electric field term $\left(F = q\vec{E}\right)$, and that with some manipulation, we can rewrite the second term on the right as the magnetic component of the force. I actually see the magnetic component easily (through some cross-product manipulation), however, I do not see how the first term on the right can be written as the electric component of the force. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $e(\frac{\partial A_0}{\partial X^p} - \frac{\partial A_p}{\partial t}) + e\dot{X^n}(\frac{\partial A_n}{\partial X^p} - \frac{\partial A_p}{\partial X^n})$...

> ...however, I do not see how the first term on the write can be written as the electric component of the force. Can someone explain this?

The $A^0$ component is what you might usually call the "electric potential" $\phi$.

The spatial components $A^p$ are the components of what you would usually call the "vector potential" $\vec A$.

By definition, the electric field is:
$$
\vec E = -\vec \nabla {\phi} - \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \vec A}{\partial t}
$$

The context is not entirely clear, but it looks like one of the signs of the term you wrote will flip when you raise the index in the numerator (depending on if you are using the mostly-plus or mostly-minus metric) and you will see that the term is the component of the electric field written above.

Comment: could you explain "The $A_0$ component is what you might usually call the "electric potential" $\phi$." - is this a definition?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. In electrodynamics we have the electric scalar potential, typically denoted $\phi$, and the vector potential $\vec A$ (with three components). These are united in the single four-potential $A^\mu = (\phi, \vec A)$ (in units where $c=1$), or $A^\mu = (\phi/c, \vec A)$ in units where $c$ is written explicitly.

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber Yes. But, also, I wrote the $A$ symbol with the upper index $0$ on purpose. Depending on your metric convention $A^0$ and $A_0$ are not necessarily the same.

Comment: yeah, sorry i copied and pasted what you said and it got messed up in that process. anyways, can you explain the quoted sentence @hft

Comment: its not that i dont know what four vectors are... it's exactly what i asked that i dont understand, which is why is $A^0$ the electric potential. commenting a wiki link that someone can easily look up isnt helpful, so please just dont comment if you dont have information to share. thanks! @Ghoster

Comment: " 'The A0 component is what you might usually call the "electric potential" ϕ.' - is this a definition?" Yes it is the usual definition of the four-vector scalar potential. Was there something else you were wondering about? @Relativisticcucumber

Comment: yes, so i think normally the four vectors show that there is some type of relationship between the first component and the last three (e.g. space and time, energy and momentum, etc.), but i am a bit surprised to see these two (A and phi) together since im used to them not interacting. them being in the same four vector implies to me that they do interact somehow, so i was wondering how this can happen or if this is the wrong way to look at it? @hft

Comment: The components of the four vector $(\phi, \vec A)$ do have a special relationship. One special relationship is the fact that they combine to form the electric field. In electrostatics we only need the field $\phi$, but in electrodynamics we need both the field $\phi$ and $\vec A$. This is because the magnetic field is $\vec B = \vec \nabla \times \vec A$ and in electrodynamics a changing magnetic field induces an electric field (hence the time derivative on the $\vec A$ term in the electric field expression).

Comment: Another special relationship that can exist between $\phi$ and $\vec A$ is a gauge-fixing condition. For example, in the Lorentz gauge the fields $\phi$ and $\vec A$ are related by $\partial_\mu A^{\mu}=0$.